# How do I convert from larger integers to smaller integers using AVX2 and SSE?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, simd, avx

Is there an efficient way to convert a larger integer type down to a smaller integer type (with truncation of course) using AVX2 and SSE?

Such as:

- int16 -> int8
- int32 -> int16 / int32 -> int8
- int64 -> int32 / int64 -> int16 / int64 -> int8

I know AVX-512 has the instructions:

- vpmovqb
- vpmovwb

Which correspond to intrinsics like:

- _mm512_cvtepi16_epi8  (AVX512 Byte and Word ISA)
- _mm512_cvtepi32_epi8  (AVX512 Foundation)
- _mm512_cvtepi32_epi16 (AVX512 Foundation)
- _mm512_cvtepi64_epi8  (AVX512 Foundation)
- _mm512_cvtepi64_epi16 (AVX512 Foundation)
- _mm512_cvtepi64_epi32 (AVX512 Foundation)

which handle integer type narrowing conversions but how do you accomplish this in AVX2 and SSE which have no such instructions?

Please note that while there are 128 and 256 bit overloads for the above AVX512 intrinsics, they still require AVX512 at runtime. I'm looking for ways to accomplish the same things using only AVX2 and/or SSE instructions.

I know this a lot to ask, if you don't want to give me the full answer I understand. Just please explain to me or help me find an algorithm I can replicate for each conversion.

Also please specify if your answer will work for both signed and unsigned integers or otherwise.

Thank you very much.

To clarify; I don't plan on unpacking this data later. I want to use vectorized narrowing conversions in a number of applications such as:

- Code page conversion (ie UTF32 -> UTF8) (I know it's not as simple as converting the data type)
- Database translation (connecting 2 completely different databases and transferring data between them where the data types of the cells in the tables are different)
- Fast Math approximations
- and more!

pretty much anything you can do with:
int32_t y = some_func();
int8_t x = static_cast<int8_t>(y);

But vectorized. I've measured the performance of our code (sorry NDA, can't show any here) and found that we spend a lot of time on type conversion. Particularly narrowing conversions. The compiler does a pretty good job of vectorizing small->BIG conversions with sign extension using the instructions available with AVX2 but narrowing conversions don't seem to get vectorized much at all.

Also to clarify some more. I want a means of casting that behaves like static_cast (as in with truncation)

Comment: It depends on where you want the results to go, as in how they are packed/spread over a vector. Maybe the "default" answer is to pack the result together tightly, that's actually a shuffle (AVX2 has those). But there are other options. For example: leaving the result in every other element (interspersed with junk), which costs *zero* instructions (the input is already of that form). Or interspersed with zeroes, which costs an AND instruction. What do you need?

Comment: Or if you're doing this just for data density of your SIMD processing but unpacking later (or if order doesn't matter), interleave with `psllw` by 8 / `pand` / `por` is possible to combine elements from two vectors into the low/high halves of the 16-bit element that contained them.

Comment: There are some existing Q&As about packing, many covering just one of the specific cases you mention; across all such Q&As you'll find a few different strategies for different element sizes.  A useful answer might link some of those for details on specific cases.  (e.g. a single vector vs. whole arrays that make it worth combining multiple vectors of data to together with a tree of pack instructions, instead of one `vpshufb`)

Comment: N.B.: The behavior of `int8_t x = static_cast<int8_t>(y);` is implementation defined if `y` does not fit into `int8_t`. By "truncation" do you mean "wrap-around", e.g. `int8_t(-129) == 127`?

Comment: @chtz: This is an x86 question, so I'm pretty confident truncation means truncating the bit-pattern, like `_mm512_cvtepi16_epi8` does.  Since x86 uses 2's complement signed integers, yes that means wrap-around.

Answer (score 1):

One good way is `pshufb` instruction, exposed as `_mm_shuffle_epi8` or `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` intrinsics. On modern CPUs that instruction is pretty fast: the latency is 1 cycle, and they can run 2 of them per clock.

Here’s an example which converts int32 -> int16, untested. By changing the shuffle magic vector, you can implement the rest of the conversations with the same code.

```
// Convert int32 lanes into int16 with truncation
inline __m128i cvtepi32_epi16( __m256i x )
{
    // Make a shuffle constant vector
    // If you also need 16-byte version, move this to global variable,
    // to reuse the lower 16 bytes of the same constant
    const __m256i shuffle = _mm256_setr_epi8(
        0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13 );

    // Move these bytes
    // Unfortunately that instruction can only move within 16-byte halves.
    // Fortunately, it can selectively zero out bytes, so a bitwise OR is enough to combine
    x = _mm256_shuffle_epi8( x, shuffle );

    // Split into halves
    const __m128i low = _mm256_castsi256_si128( x );
    const __m128i high = _mm256_extracti128_si256( x, 1 );

    // Produce the result
    return _mm_or_si128( low, high );
}
```

For SSE vectors it’s even more efficient than for AVX2, you only need a single `_mm_shuffle_epi8` instruction. BTW for both SSE and AVX, that instruction [can load](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb) the second argument directly from memory, i.e. even if that code is not inlined, it does not requite a separate load to fetch the permutation  constant.

P.S. Signed/unsigned is irrelevant for truncation, the downcasting operation is identical between the two. Signed/unsigned only matters if you want to saturate instead of truncate, but `static_cast` doesn't saturate anything, it truncates.

Comment: For i64->i32 use `vpermd` for __m256i, and use `pshufd` for __m128i.

Comment: @aqrit: or `shufps` to pack dwords from two 128-bit source vectors.  Like here after `extract` if you only had AVX1 but still wanted to pack 4-byte chunks of a `__m256i` for some reason.  (You're right that with AVX2, you'd just use one `vpermd` for the whole thing, not two separate shuffles plus an OR!)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, but the OP asked 6 questions, and this answers all 6. Fixed shuffle is only good for one of them, can’t even implement 16-byte int64->int32 because it can’t selectively zero out lanes.

Comment: Sure, but as your example you picked the one case where there's a *much* better strategy than vpshufb + extract + or even for a single vector, let alone for arrays of multiple vectors where one should `vpand` / `vpackssdw` / `vpermq` for example.

Comment: Re: the 16-byte case: sure, one `vpshufb` is a viable approach if you have separate 16-byte vectors in a loop, and actually need them zero extended (rather than say `shufps` two together + `movlps` / `movhps` stores of pairs of int32_t).  But it requires a load of a constant which could miss in cache (if you're only using it once, not repeated in a loop), you could also `shufps` with a zeroed vector if you care about the high half being zero for some reason, instead of just `pshufd` to feed `movq` or `movlps` to reg or memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair point, updated

Comment: Hmm, maybe more interesting to demo 32->8.  For 32->16, another strategy is equally good on most CPUs, and better on Alder Lake, and slightly on Zen1: `vpand` / `vpextracti128` / `vpackusdw xmm`.  Still needs a 32-byte vector constant, still has two shuffle operations and a boolean.  But the shuffle is xmm, the boolean is ymm.  Zen1 runs `vpshufb ymm` as 2 uops at 1/clock throughput, though, so it's not a big advantage.  But Alder Lake E-cores have significantly better throughput for `packuswd` uops (3/clock) than for `pshufb` uops (1/clock), so `vpshufb ymm` is 2c throughput on Alder-E.

Answer (score 0):

The various PACK instructions convert int16->int8 or int32->int16 from a pair of mmx/xmm regs to a single reg, with either signed or unsigned saturation (for values that are out of range for the target type)  There is no int64->int32 version though.

Comment: The question asks for truncation, so you need to `_mm256_and_si256` your data before using it with saturating packs (the only kind available before AVX-512), and then if you need the order to match an original array, do a lane-crossing vpermq shuffle to fix up the result.  For 64->32 there's `vpermd`.  (Possibly feed it with `vpsllq ymm, 32` / `vpblendd` to get the useful parts of two YMM vectors into one, then reorder.)