# Convert int32_t to unsigned char. AVX

Tags: c++, type-conversion, sse, intrinsics, avx

Need to correctly convert YMM with 8 int32_t to XMM with 8 UNSIGNED uint8_t at the bottom, using AVX intrinsics. It should be analogue of `static_cast<uint8_t>`. It means that C++ standard rules work (modular reduction).  So we get truncation of the 2's complement bit-pattern.

For example, `(int32_t)(-1)` -> `(uint8_t)(255)`, and `+200` -> `(uint8_t)(200)` so we can't use signed or unsigned saturation to 8-bit (or even to 16-bit as an intermediate step).

I have this code as [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856006/sse-intrinsics-convert-32-bit-floats-to-unsigned-8-bit-integers):

```
packssdw xmm0, xmm0
packuswb xmm0, xmm0
movd somewhere, xmm0
```

But these commands use unsigned saturation, so we get `(int32_t)(-1)` -> `(uint8_t)(0)`.

I know `vcvttss2si` and it works correctly but only for one value. For the best performance I want to use vector registers.

Also I know about shuffling but it's enough slow for me.

So Is there another way to convert from int32_t YMM to uint8_t YMM as `static_cast<uint8_t>`?

*UPD: The comment of @chtz is answer of my question.*

Comment: If you have the idea that clear, why not just program it in assembler directly?

Comment: It unclear what your question is. What is YMM? How would you fit a DWORD into eight bits?

Comment: @TedLyngmo which idea? I show 3 variants and all of them aren't for me. So I ask for advice how to to convert correctly (as static_cast from c++) VMM with 8 int32_t values to VMM with 8 UNSIGNED int8_t values using intrinsics

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt YMM - is vector register in AVX isa (XMM for SSE, ZMM for AVX512). The size is 256 bytes so we can fill fully YMM by 8 int32_t values

Comment: @alexa I changed my idea of the question to that it needs clarity.

Comment: To avoid saturation behavior you can bit-and with `0x000000ff` before packing.

Comment: @chtz it works the way I want! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another option is [using pshufb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824699/555045) but it's inconvenient for YMM registers.

Comment: @chtz maybe also do you know the same way for int32_t->int8_t conversion without saturation and ```pshufb```? It'd be perfect!

Comment: @alexa For `int32_t` to `int8_t` without saturation, for what values do you expect different output than for `uint8_t`? (Note that the C++ behavior for signed overflow is undefined).

Comment: @chtz I want to make the similar behavior as ```static_cast<int8_t>(int32_t)```. I mean ```int32_t(128)->int8_t(-128)```. But ```packuswb``` uses saturation (with your advise ```0x000000ff` and without) so I get ```int32_t(128)->int8_t(127)```. But for me it's incorrect result

Comment: You still need to use `packuswb` `int32_t(-128) = 0xffffff80 -> 0x80 -> uint8_t(0x80) = int8_t(-128)`